# Cyber Monday Traffic Data

Tags: data-request, extracting, polling

Are there any sites/tools that provide data on how much traffic a site is currently encountering?

I'm particularly curious to see how much traffic increases on sites like Amazon.com with regard to "[Cyber Monday](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyber_Monday)". So, more appropriately, does Amazon provide any live streams or web services for such data?